# Error: Unable to find the next dep, try NPM installing?

Tags: node.js, firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I'm trying to upload a simple next js application to a firebase hosting, the first time it left me without problems, but now I get an error and even though I install everything from scratch it keeps coming out, even though all the NPM packages are installed. I get the following error when executing `firebase deploy --only hosting` error:

```
[debug] [2023-05-05T03:22:19.791Z] Error: Unable to find the next dep, try NPM installing?
    at getConfig (C:\Users\layon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\frameworks\next\index.js:336:19)
    at build (C:\Users\layon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\frameworks\next\index.js:60:46)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async prepareFrameworks (C:\Users\layon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\frameworks\index.js:193:108)
    at async deploy (C:\Users\layon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\index.js:55:13)
```

I already uninstalled and reinstalled everything, from node js, to firebase tools, I also try another simpler next project and I get the same error

Comment: I got same error, I don't know why this happen but when I run `firebase deploy --only hosting` in cmd it worked, in case when error occurred  then I just kill terminal and again do same thing. AND one thing that surprise me is that generally this error occurred when I change cursor's focus from terminal. -  (my  experiences)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, started happening right after i updated firebase tools.

there seems to be a Next.js breaking change in the latest version.
[image]

for now try installing an older version of firebase-tools (for me its 11.29.0)

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@11.29.0
```

after that look into what the breaking changes actually are.. google kinda sucks when it comes to documentation.

heres my dependencies:

```
"firebase": "^9.22.0",
"firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
"firebase-auth": "^0.1.2",
"firebase-tools": "^11.29.0",
"fs": "^0.0.1-security",
"next": "^13.3.4",
"puppeteer": "^20.1.2",
"react": "18.2.0",
```

Goodluck!

Comment: PLZ define your enviroments: nextjs version ..